# Calling CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() within a task does not set Task.IsCanceled to true

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, resharper, cancellationtokensource

If I call `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel` within the task associated with the cancellation token, the `OperationCancelledException` is correctly thrown, however, `task.IsCanceled` is NOT always updated and set to `true`, as would be expected.

The problem can be quickly demonstrated with the following nUnit test:

```cs
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{                                
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();                
}, 
cancellationTokenSource.Token);

try
{
    task.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);                
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
}

if (task.IsCanceled)
{
    Assert.Pass();
}
else
{
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

When I run this test, the test passes, however, when I DEBUG this test (using the Resharper test runner), the test fails.

I don't think this has anything to do with Resharper, I think Resharper just may be creating some conditions that perhaps expose an issue in .Net. Or, maybe I am just doing something completely wrong... **Any insights?**

Comment: Works for me in a console app... have you put breakpoints in to check that `Cancel` is being called, for example?

Comment: Yes, I've stepped through it. Ultimately, `cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` is set to `true`, but `task.IsCanceled` is still set to `false`. It is boggling my mind.

Comment: So what is `task.Status`?

Comment: @Mikeyg36 Typically this would happen if you failed to pass the cancellation token to the call to `StartNew`, and only used it in the body.

Comment: This thing is acting like schrodinger's cat. If I add `Console.WriteLine("task.Status: {0}", task.Status);` right before the if-block, the test passes. But if I remove that call, the test fails.

Comment: I put a breakpoint at `Assert.Fail` and checked task.Status in the debugger. it is set to Running.

Comment: @Mikeyg36 Don't use the cancellation token when waiting on the task.  It's causing the wait to throw and move on to the assert before the task's status gets set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the cancellation token when waiting on the `Task`. It's causing `Wait` to throw and move on to the assert before the task's status gets set.

The two things are happening in parallel, so it's actually a race condition as to whether or not it happens, hence the issues you've had trying to replicate the issues and the correct behavior when debugging.

Comment: But isn't the exception only supposed to be thrown when I call `cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, which only happens once?

Comment: @Mikeyg36 `task.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);` throws if the token is cancelled before the task is considered completed.  It also throws if the task being waited on is faulted/cancelled.

Comment: Ah, so `task.wait` is throwing as soon `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` is called, but then the task continues execution asynchronously until `cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, at which point it itself throws an exception. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Mikeyg36 Yes.  The exact timings can actually vary a bit.  The point is simply that `Wait` can continue on before the task is completed.  The exact possible interweivings are numerous.  The `Wait` moving on and the task being marked as cancelled both happen at some indeterminate amount of time after the token is cancelled.  If the `Wait` reaches `IsCancelled` first, your test fails.  If it reaches it second, your test passes.

Comment: But isn't this a correct use-case? Aren't you supposed to use the cancellation token exactly like this: pass it into a task, `Wait` for it, then check whether it is canceled or not. To say that `Wait` can continue on before the task is completed seems to defeat the main invariant of `Wait`, no?

Comment: @Mikeyg36 As I said in the answer, you should not be passing the token to `Wait`.  The task is already set up to cancel itself when the token is cancelled, thus the wait should wait forever, knowing that the task its waiting on isn't going to be running for longer than the cancellation token defines for it.  You should only be using the cancellation token with `Wait` if the task being waited on *isn't* using the token, and in that case you obviously wouldn't expect the task to be cancelled (or even finished) when `Wait` completed.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers. I didn't realize that the token in `Task.Wait' was used for cancelling the **waiting**, not the task. Jon Skeet actually shed some light [here](http://askjonskeet.com/answer/17919812/TaskWait-Method-(CancellationToken))